# Does windows still need CR+LF combination for enter key?

Tags: java, mysql, database, windows, enter

Can  `\r\n` (i.e CR+LF) be converted to a single character in windows so that when I enter a string with <kbd>Enter</kbd> in it into my database's table(nvarchar type column), it'll only consume one character instead of two(`CR` - 1 character & `LF` - 1 character )?

eg:-

> `hello`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`world`

The text within the code block are of 11 characters, counting the enter as 1 character; but as mentioned in this post, windows counts enter as two characters i.e. the above string example is counted as 12 characters in windows . What if my database's predefined column size was 11? Which is why I'm asking if our community members would know if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key could somehow be modulated to consume only one character in MySql database?

Comment: Really, why do you care whether it occupies one character or two?

Comment: because the database column was designed assuming that it's length will be equal to the number of characters allowed to be entered by the user and I need to support just as many characters without modifying/increasing the column size.

Comment: You should post some code, *as is*, this is unclear. What do you mean by " when I enter a string with Enter in it into my database's table"

Comment: @GordonLinoff see, if the edited question is easier to understand... It's just a peculiar bug that I'm facing.

Comment: just strip `\r` before insertion into the DB, no?

Comment: right, but will striping \r not affect the accurate retrieval back of the text in windows?

Comment: @codeforce1 . . . Add the `\r` back in when you fetch the value.  You can handle that part with a computed column.

Comment: wish it were that simple, it so happens that the code I'm fixing ain't the only one retrieving data from that table,if I did take that obvious step, other codes dependent on that table will then end up with the wrong value.

Comment: Well, if other code assumes there is a CRLF in the value, then there has to be a CRLF in the value, yes?  You can't safely change the string format without examining the other code to see what the impact of the change will be.